# Angular2 Observables - Creating my own - subscriber undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, rxjs

I can't quite tell if this is a scoping issue or an issue with how I've set up my observables, but maybe you can help.

**Firstly, my logic.** My overall aim is to be able to check if some data is held locally before sending off a http.get request for it. What I'd like to do is return the locally held data back if it exists, and I thought that I could make this return an observable so that I could subscribe to the output of this function regardless of if it returned local data or remote data. Any thoughts on this logic would be appreciated!

I am following [this blog post by Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services) to implement my own observable. I am running into a problem where I cannot get my Observer to be defined in my `getData` function.

[Here is Cory's working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCf6dqq7KAg5NLqKjg7D?p=preview)

[Here is my not-working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/f7GXUisIrKMT7CakW7TK?p=preview) - You can see in the log that `this._dataObserver` in the service is undefined, whereas in Cory's it is. This is what is causing me issues.

Here are snippets from the code:

App.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <landing-page></landing-page>    
  `,
  providers: [DataService],
  directives: [LandingPageComponent]
})
export class App {
  constructor() { }
}

bootstrap(App, [HTTP_BINDINGS])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

LandingPageComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'landing-page',
  template : `
    hello
  `,
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit{
  data : Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(
    private _dataService : DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._dataService.data$;
    this._dataService.getData();
  }
}
```

DataService

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

   data$ : Observable<any[]>; // data stream
   private _baseUrl: string;
   private _dataObserver : Observer<any[]>;
   private _dataStore : {
    data : any[]
   };

  constructor (
    private _http: Http
  ) {
    this._baseUrl  = 'http://56e05c3213da80110013eba3.mockapi.io/api';
    this.data$ =  new Observable(observer => this._todosObserver = observer).share();
    this._dataStore = { data: [] };
  }

  /** **************
  * Public functions
  *****************/

  getData () {
    this._http.get(`${this._baseUrl}/todos`)
      .map(data => data.json())
      .subscribe( data => {
      this._dataStore.data = data;
      console.log(this._dataObserver);   //<------ This is undefined for me!
      this._dataObserver.next(this.data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('couldn\'t load data! ' + error );
    });

  }

}
```

Thank you for any thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_dataObserver` is null because you don't subscribe on the associated observable. Don't forget that observables are lazy...

You could try the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this._dataService.data$.subscribe(data => { // <-----
    console.log(data);
  });
  this._dataService.getData();
}
```

**Edit**

In addition, there is a typo in your code:

```
this.data$ =  new Observable(observer => this._todosObserver = observer).share();
```

You should use `_dataObserver` instead of `_todosObserver`:

```
this.data$ =  new Observable(observer => this._dataObserver = observer).share();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error related to the Observable not being defied before the call makes it's was back to the landingPageComponent. The service cannot call `this._dataObserver.next(this.data)` because `this._dataObserver` is undefined. This is the same error as I was getting before I added this line of code to my component.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo but you use `_todosObserver` instead of `_dataObserver` in you code when initializing your observable. See `new Observable(observer => this._todosObserver = observer).share()`.

Comment: How annoying, the solution was that simple!! Thanks Thierry, I obviously needed a fresh pair of eyes. If you put this as an answer I will accept it. **EDIT** I needed to do this as well, so I have marked this as the correct answer. Thanks!